# ios best practices for Arranging multiple actions for UiTableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a table view with section header . Each Item and section header has Check box for multi selection. I have the following controls(actions that I need to use)

1. Delete
2. Copy
3. Forward
4. Push into vegetable list ( this is a UitableView, a new ViewController)
5. Push into hardware list
6. Edit
7. Push to save list

Now for all these I have icons, Actually I am making replica of Android app, and android app is showing these actions at very bottom of screen.

**My case:**

I am using Tab bar in iOS, so as I said above in android app I am showing these action at bottom, so How can I show these action? and what is the best practice for it. I know it can be managed in a way as iOS mail app is handling by giving more button when we swipe the item, but my problem is user can select multiple headers/sections and perform any action on it. this is the main problem of app right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you’re already using the iOS Mail app as a guide, you can take a look at how it handles actions on multiple items.

You press “Edit” to enable edit mode in the table view, and then the actions are listed on the bar at the bottom once you’ve selected the ones you want.

See attached screenshots.

If you can’t fit all your actions at the bottom, perhaps you could have the most common actions there, and a “more” button that opens an action sheet presenting the rest of them.

[image: First press edit]

[image: Then select multiple cells and the actions to perform on them appear at the bottom]